# I want to programmatically launch a browser with a URL, wait for it to finish, then close the browser

Tags: c#, html, firefox, internet-explorer-9, chromium

I have created an Html 5 page that provides important server-side functionality.  Unfortunately, it must be run in an Html 5 browser (Chrome, IE9, or Firefox) with a canvas to produce the results I need.  It is completely self contained, taking needed parameters through the URL, and is ready to be closed when the OnLoad event is ready to send.  So far so good.

The following process needs to be automated (no human eyes or interaction) and will be run from within a web service (not run from within a browser).  Ideally, I don't want to waste extra cycles with busy wait, or delay the result by waiting for long time periods simply hoping the process has finished.  I need to:

1. Open a browser (preferably Chrome) with a URL, using C#.
2. Wait for the page to completely finish loading - ideally receiving a callback of some kind.
3. Close the browser page when finished, again with C#.

We've tried using IE9.  There is C# support to launch IE9, Wait until not Busy, and gracefully Close the browser; however, the page loads resources asynchronously (there is no way around this), and so we get the signal that it is no longer busy during the resource load - instead of when the page has finished.  Adding busy wait would consume valuable server-side cpu cycles.

A simple Create Process call would be nice, but would only work if the browser could close itself with some html - but thanks to security measures in the browsers, I can't find a reliable way to use html commands to close a browser that was launched from command-line (I did see you can close tabs spawned from an already opened page - firefox only, but this doesn't help).

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this goal?  Again - there is no human involvement in any of the process, no human eyes will ever see the page or interact with it in any way.  The page only runs on the server machine, and will never be deployed to a client machine.

Comment: You should consider using the `WebBrowser` control, which is basically the same version of IE as installed on your system, but which can be programmatically controlled. Use it if you can use it from a desktop application, not if you need to use it from code running in a service.

Comment: [Watin](http://watin.org/) shall do it, not sure about html5 though, but I guess it would work and it's a good place to start.

Comment: You might be able to use [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/intl/no/chrome/chromeframe/) in IE and still be able to use the IE components from your application.

Comment: Yes, the WebBrowser is what I'm talking about with the wait until not busy call.  The wait until not busy returns true to early.  If you know what else to try with that, I'm interested.  Again though, I don't need to interact with the page, just to open it, wait for it to finish, then close it.

Comment: I have no application, no buttons, no text fields, no user interaction.  No frame.  The entire thing is launched from within a web service, not from a page, not from a browser.  The entire page must be launched from c#, run to completion, then closed - and let C# know when it's finished.

Comment: Watin looks interesting, though I can't seem to find good documentation on it, or how to do the simple thing I want: launch, wait, and close.  I don't need click or interaction functionality.

Comment: If you just want the web service tickled why can't you just use cURL?

Comment: cURL looks very interesting, but I need HTML 5 functionality.  The page renders to a canvas and saves the result to file.  cURL does not seem capable of this.

Comment: oh I see.  Wait, you want to save the file locally?  I think maybe node.js on the server and then deliver the file via cURL

Comment: Does node.js launch an HTML 5 browser window?  I already know how to render the image I want and save it - but it needs HTML 5.  What I don't know how to do is launch the browser with the html, wait until finished, and close it all from c#.

Comment: node.js will let you run all the javascript code you have on a canvas element, in this way you can use the existing code on the server side and the client software won't need to be maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the WebBrowser control to load the HTML.  Once you get the data back, use an ObjectForScripting to call a c# method to notify when done.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/130267/Call-a-C-Method-From-JavaScript-Hosted-in-a-WebBro

You dont really have to even show the  webbrowser control.

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope it helps!

Comment: The link is gold - mostly the object for scripting callback.  Thank you - I think I can use this to accomplish the task (though it'll still be a little messier than I would have liked).  I upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Automating the browser - thats what [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) does. I think it will be a good fit for the task, and there's good C# support. It can even run the browser on a remote machine using the Selenium RC server.

Comment: I don't desire to interact with the page after I've launched it.  Selenium seems serious overkill to simply launch a page, wait for it to finish, then close it.  Selenium is billed as a testing tool (click buttons, fill in text fields, etc).

Comment: I also just researched Selenium a bit.  I don't want to launch a test environment, which would then have to be interacted with by a human.  I am not running tests.  This is part of a web service.  The service must create the browser, launch the page, wait for completion, and close the page - all without human interaction.

Comment: Selenium doesn't need human interaction, it is designed to be scripted - which you can do from C# using the WebDriver API. Selenium is not just for testing, it is for all sorts of browser automation.